# How to use a custom URL with aspx view engine with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use a URL like www.mysite.com/india/population-dec2013 instead of www.mysite.com/india/dec2013.

Later one is straight forward way to go with MVC. But I want to insert extra "popluation-" in it. And I want to show population for India in Dec2013.

Answer (score 0):

Usual WebForms application can also use RouteModule that MVC uses. So you can go with it, and customize your routes.

Here is sample and description of it -

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx
- http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2010/02/28/web-forms-routing-in-asp-net-4/